# RSA Encrypt Handle invalid issue

Tags: c#, cryptography, rsa, public-key-encryption, private-key

I am trying to encrypt a text and the decrypt it using public private key pair. I need the keys to handled as string. So I convert these key from string to RSAParameters. But when i try to encrypt the text, it throws me an error as "The handle is not valid".

```
static RSAParameters _publicKey = new RSAParameters();
static RSAParameters _privateKey = new RSAParameters();
static string _strPublicKey = "-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----\r\nMIIBIjANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQEFAAOCAQ8AMIIBCgKCAQEAsG5sBbnH7gXkrExzNOeK\r\nEjoRDHUH5uU+crH52Z1uXCEx8LiFow8RwrvZGqjYXgBwxzqOQwHJt3utoNVY0niP\r\nHjfPXwKTk79PkeET/mtRar1gEcCOr0/hgHxT3YGlQLw2ugVIulMzlUBRY4rceNv3\r\nEiSZ+4cnO04hJ6UiftrCfwTe6q9Hadp6B6SX+N9hgcHhRX4iR/VYUf/6cvN+NAgb\r\ntuF0Dk61C6ulh2Gvdj2TBCLaq1LPF5H+ghrRxjK/Zn6MG9BW2ju9g8zYKuufaaaM\r\ndbTmN+Z4f27nEOxFq5wWqeaWl53yrMia6xnOi7vtU8zcwBL7jSLgwrkyO8LabCdz\r\neQIDAQAB\r\n-----END PUBLIC KEY-----";
static string _strPrivateKey = "-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----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\r\nDsUL5Ia5W7/Cm7d0/nqchUCkRslIsH+bfGj0NZ7qcE5H1D8Ee0A=\r\n-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----";
static void Main(string[] args)
{
  var message = "Hello World!";
  var data = Encrypt(message);
  var res = Decrypt(data);
}

private static RSAParameters GetRSAParameters(string pPublicKey)
{
  byte[] lDer;

  //Set RSAKeyInfo to the public key values. 
  int lBeginStart = "-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----".Length;
  int lEndLenght = "-----END PUBLIC KEY-----".Length;
  string KeyString = pPublicKey.Substring(lBeginStart, (pPublicKey.Length - lBeginStart - lEndLenght));
  lDer = Convert.FromBase64String(KeyString);


  //Create a new instance of the RSAParameters structure.
  RSAParameters lRSAKeyInfo = new RSAParameters();

  lRSAKeyInfo.Modulus = GetModulus(lDer);
  lRSAKeyInfo.Exponent = GetExponent(lDer);

  return lRSAKeyInfo;
}

private static byte[] GetModulus(byte[] pDer)
{
  //Size header is 29 bits
  //The key size modulus is 128 bits, but in hexa string the size is 2 digits => 256 
  string lModulus = BitConverter.ToString(pDer).Replace("-", "").Substring(58, 256);

  return StringHexToByteArray(lModulus);
}

private static byte[] GetExponent(byte[] pDer)
{
  int lExponentLenght = pDer[pDer.Length - 3];
  string lExponent = BitConverter.ToString(pDer).Replace("-", "").Substring((pDer.Length * 2) - lExponentLenght * 2, lExponentLenght * 2);

  return StringHexToByteArray(lExponent);
}

public static byte[] StringHexToByteArray(string hex)
{
  return Enumerable.Range(0, hex.Length)
                   .Where(x => x % 2 == 0)
                   .Select(x => Convert.ToByte(hex.Substring(x, 2), 16))
                   .ToArray();
}

public static string Encrypt(string mess)
{
  string response = "";
  var input = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(mess);
  using (var rsa = new RSACryptoServiceProvider(1024))
  {
    rsa.PersistKeyInCsp = false;
    rsa.ImportParameters(GetRSAParameters(_strPublicKey));
    var decrypt = rsa.Encrypt(input, true);
    response = Convert.ToBase64String(decrypt);
  }
  return response;
}

public static string Decrypt(string mess)
{
  string response = "";
  var input = Convert.FromBase64String(mess);
  using (var rsa = new RSACryptoServiceProvider(2048))
  {
    rsa.PersistKeyInCsp = false;
    rsa.ImportParameters(GetRSAParameters(_strPublicKey));
    var decrypt = rsa.Decrypt(input, false);
    response = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(decrypt);
  }
  return response;
}
```

Above is the code that I am using to encrypt and decrypt. After the conversion, I convert them to string and pass it to the decrypt function. Please advice

Answer (score 0):

Your attempt to read the DER is definitely lacking.  Possibly because you have a 2048-bit key and your "parser" *at best* only works for a 1024-bit key (though I'm having trouble deciding what key it could legitimately read).

Your public key hex is

```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```

The DER breakdown (because I can't help myself) is

```
 30 82 01 22
    30 0D
       06 09 2A 86 48 86 F7 0D 01 01 01
       05 00
    03
       82 01 0F
          00
          30 82 01 0A
             02 82 01 01
                00B06E6C05B9C7EE05E4AC4C7334E78A123A110C7507E6E53E72B1F9D99D6E5C
                2131F0B885A30F11C2BBD91AA8D85E0070C73A8E4301C9B77BADA0D558D2788F
                1E37CF5F029393BF4F91E113FE6B516ABD6011C08EAF4FE1807C53DD81A540BC
                36BA0548BA5333954051638ADC78DBF7122499FB87273B4E2127A5227EDAC27F
                04DEEAAF4769DA7A07A497F8DF6181C1E1457E2247F55851FFFA72F37E34081B
                B6E1740E4EB50BABA58761AF763D930422DAAB52CF1791FE821AD1C632BF667E
                8C1BD056DA3BBD83CCD82AEB9F69A68C75B4E637E6787F6EE710EC45AB9C16A9
                E696979DF2ACC89AEB19CE8BBBED53CCDCC012FB8D22E0C2B9323BC2DA6C2773
                79
             02 03
                010001
```

Which is the ASN.1 equivalent of

```
SEQUENCE
  SEQUENCE
    OBJECT IDENTIFIER id-rsaEncryption
    NULL
  BIT STRING (0 bits unused) (wrapping)
    SEQUENCE
      INTEGER (positive) 0xB06E...7379
      INTEGER 0x010001
```

Your modulus extractor skips 29 bytes and reads the next 128.  (Why it does byte[] => hex => substring => byte[] instead of doing `new byte[size]` and `Buffer.BlockCopy` is beyond me).  The problem is, your key is a 2048-bit key (the modulus length is 0x0101, and once we remove the sign-padding byte it's 0x0100 bytes long, with the high bit set, so 256*8 = 2048 bit modulus).  So you need to have read 256 bytes.  And, worse, because the payload is bigger than expected, it doesn't start at the offset you think it does.  So where you should end up with `B0 6E 6C ... 27 73 79` (after skipping the padding byte) you ended up with `82 01 01 00 *B0 6E 6C ... A5 22 7E` (the asterisk marking the desired start of your payload).  So, that's bad, and you are definitely not encrypting what you think you are. (The A5 22 7E sequence occurs on the line starting with 36BA, ending with 3 bytes left to go on that line)

What's worse is the `GetExponent` method.  It seems to try to combine actual DER reading with presupposing what the value is.  It should conclude `01 00 01`, but it reads the first `01` of the payload as a length, then uses that length to count from the end.  So the exponent value ends up being just `01`.  The RSA algorithm doesn't work with `e=1`, and what's happening is probably that a post-encryption self-test decided that the results were garbage, and the Win32 crypto library concluded that the problem is that the caller gave it something that wasn't a valid key handle, as opposed to a valid handle to an invalid key. In addition to not understanding the byte[] => hex => substring => byte[] pattern here I don't understand why this code decided that pDer[-3] (to use syntax from another language) was the length value.  DER can only be read "left to right", and if it knew "the exponent is always 0x010001" then a) that'd be length-encoded at pDer[-4] b) just reading the last three bytes would be forgivable and c) given how many assumptions this code makes it would've made more sense to just blindly assume 0x010001.

So, you need to a) replace your parser with either a correct parser or at least a specialized one which functions at your desired keysize and b) never use that private key for anything important, since you just posted it to the Internet (and the private key variable wasn't even used in this problem).